# How big should a Firefox toolbar button be?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, icons, toolbar

**What size, in pixels, should a custom Firefox toolbar button icon be?**

I've seen quite a variety. Most commonly I've come across 32x32, 24x24 and 16x16 but also 10x10, 15x15, 16x14, etc. I cannot find a definitive reference.

Also see: [How big should an Internet Explorer icon be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711105/how-big-should-an-internet-explorer-icon-be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how I found it, but the [Creating toolbar buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_toolbar_buttons#Icon_size) article at the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/) defines Firefox big icon size as 24x24 and small icon size as 16x16.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive size given.

The size of icon will depend on whether the user has large/small icons enabled. 32x32 is generally a good mid-point.