# How big should an Internet Explorer toolbar icon be?

Tags: internet-explorer, graphics, size, icons

I'm trying adding my own toolbar icon to Internet Explorer but am unsure what size it should be.

- The [Designing Toolbar Icons for Internet Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346732.aspx) articles on TechNet indicates 20x20 and 16x16 pixels.
- Messages ([1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx?msg=1728225#xx1728225xx), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx?msg=2548229#xx2548229xx)) in the [Internet Explorer Toolbar (Deskband) Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx) at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) imply 22x22 and 16x16 pixels.

Using Internet Explorer 7, icons that are 20x20 pixels seem to get stretched. Measuring shows they should be at least 24x24. Anyone have a definitive reference?

---

Alternatively, where does Internet Explorer get its existing toolbar icons from - I could measure it then! I presume its one of the system DLLs, but which one?

Also see: [How big should a Firefox toolbar button be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558069/how-big-should-a-firefox-toolbar-button-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by a process of trial and error, it appears that icons sized **24x24 pixels** are not rescaled. At least, that is the case with Internet Explorer 7.0.6001.18000. Would still like find a definitive reference for IE7 and ideally other versions too.

---

Another way to confirm it:

```
int x, y;
HIMAGELIST hImageList = (HIMAGELIST) SendMessage(m_hWndToolbar, TB_GETIMAGELIST, 0, 0);
ImageList_GetIconSize(hImageList, &x, &y);
ATLTRACE("Image size %ux%u", x, y);
```

Output:

```
Image list 24x24
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume we're talking about favicons? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) defines them as 16x16 in the first sentence.

The top four [Google hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=favicon+size) all indicate 16x16.

- http://www.animatedfavicon.com/question/what-favicon-size.php
- http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html
- http://www.clickfire.com/favicon-tutorial/
- http://www.favicon.cc/

Comment: No, I'm talking about toolbar icons. As added by a plugin.